# import spreadsheet error: "Automation server can't create object"

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2007, import, ms-office

When importing an excel spreadsheet in Sharepoint, the following error pops up in a web dialog with the following message-"Automation server can't create object". What is wrong? does office needs to be installed to import spreadsheets or will installing the primary interop assemblies for Office fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Office must be installed in the server, and the xls version must not be newer than the server's version